# How to regulate fan speed of external USB fan?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, speedfan

I installed SpeedFan, but the only fan showing up is the one inside my laptop for the CPU.

Since today, I have an additional fan which is external below the [Fellowes® - Precision Cooler Laptop Riser](http://www.fellowes.com/row/en/Products/Pages/product-details.aspx?prod=FT-8018801).

How can I regulate the fan speed of this external fan which is plugged into my laptop via USB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. USB only powers it. There's no data interchange. You can't lower the voltage on the usb.